# Android : Missing EXTRA PAYPAL CONFIGURATION. To avoid this error, set EXTRA PAYPAL CONFIGURATION in both PayPalService, and the initializing activity

Tags: android, paypal, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the paypal  in a Android environment.
Once I call the PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI function, the application hangs and I get following errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService@4191d328 with Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.demoPayPal.android/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION. To avoid this error, set EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION in both PayPalService, and the initializing activity.

    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:119)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4873)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:528)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION. To avoid this error, set EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION in both PayPalService, and the initializing activity.
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2610)
    ... 10 more
```

Code:

```
String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
                                String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.paypal_clientID);
                                PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT).clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID).merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy")).merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
                                PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE, amount, currency);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
                                intent.putExtra(com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
```

Has anyone came across such a situation? Have you got anything to propose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION.`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya :Can you know the solution?

Comment: Check code too, I have updated my question.
Please have a look.. @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0):

actually this is due to your `PayPalCofiguration` object being null.
before starting the `PayPalService`, you are setting the `EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION` with `putExtra`. So if the config which youll pass here is null, the crash will happen. Check for your config being non null. That should solve the issue, Cheers.